# Mysql query order by with longtext value as int

Tags: mysql

I tried below query it giving me error. what was the error

```
SELECT listingsdbelements_field_value
FROM default_en_listingsdbelements
ORDER BY CAST(listingsdbelements_field_value AS INT) ASC
```

> Query: SELECT listingsdbelements_field_value FROM
>   default_en_listingsdbelements ORDER BY
>   CAST(listingsdbelements_field_value AS INT) AS...
>
> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'INT) ASC   LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use signed or unsigned depending upon your needs.

```
SELECT listingsdbelements_field_value
FROM default_en_listingsdbelements
ORDER BY CAST(listingsdbelements_field_value AS UNSIGNED) ASC
```

From MySQL -
SIGNED  Converts value to SIGNED type, which is a signed 64-bit integer
UNSIGNED    Converts value to UNSIGNED type, which is an unsigned 64-bit integer